# transform on a laravel collection is not changing an attribute

Tags: laravel, collections, transform

In the following code, the "liked_by_me" column remains unchanged but the "newAttr" column is added.

```
    $commentList->transform(function($item, $key) {
        $item->liked_by_me == null ? $item->liked_by_me = false : $item->liked_by_me = true;
        $item->liked_by_me == null ? $item->newAttr = false : $item->newAttr = true;
        return $item;
    });
```

The $commentList collection is the result of a read from the DB using a standard model for the comments table.  I am running Laravel 8

There seems to be no way to change an existing attribute in the rows of the resulting collection, but adding new attributes works.  I have also tried various iterations using ->map() and ->each and nothing seems to allow me to alter an attribute of a row in a collection retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

use the map function, it works for me

```
$commentList->map(function($item){
  //DO YOUR STUFF HERE

  return $item;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a null comparision with "==". Use is_null() function instead.